# Sometimes the tongue talks at your life / the head’s cost

Tags: proverbs, sentence-request

Imagine someone had a very bad tongue / mouth [in our language "tongue" is the figurative responsible body limb for what is said and not mouth] and speaks very bluntly and without considering what will their words cause to happen or what further consequences their words will have.

There is a metaphor in our language which says:

> - Sometimes the tongue talks at your life / the head’s cost"

meaning that what you say may lead you even to death. Actually it refers to ancient kings in our land who all expected all people, no matter who, just respect them and obey every single commands which they used to issue at the time, otherwise, they may be killed.

I need to know if there is any equivalent proverb for such an effect of what you say in English?

I found another English saying, but I guess it doesn't work either.

> - [Chickens come home to roost](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/chickens-come-home-to-roost).

Comment: Yeah, "chickens come home to roost" means something more like "the consequences of your actions are obvious now".

Comment: What is your culture/native language? Perhaps this might help: [LINK](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Category:Proverbs_by_language)  It is wikiquote, so I won't defend it, but it might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make one up:

> When tongues wag heads roll.

Comment: Terrific, I love this answer!

Comment: Awesome! Just could you possibly explain it in a bit more details please @TRomano. :)

Comment: *Heads will roll* is a figurative phrase that means "some people will be punished" (such as by being fired from their jobs) which is based on the literal idea of decapitation, capital punishment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ["Loose lips sink ships"](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/237250.html).  It's a slogan that originated as a warning during World War Two, that careless talk might lead to disaster:

*Loose lips* = careless talking
*might sink ships* = the enemy might be listening, and some piece of information you carelessly revealed might lead to an enemy victory over our forces

It's not exactly the same as your example, because the danger is mostly to other people, not the speaker, but it has some of the same sense, I think.

Comment: Yes, it has, but I am looking for a proverb which conveys that a bad tongue can lead to every bad consequences @Standnon. :)

Answer (score 1):

Might is right.

Punishment is lame but it comes.

This might be it!  **A still tongue makes a wise head.**  It is not identical.

Comment: Is far as I know, "mihgt is right" means the more you have power, the more you have freedom of action, hence you will be more mighty @Willow Rex

Comment: @A-friend  you are correct. I was trying to find anything that remotely worked for you. However, it boils down to there is no proverb/phrase or idiom that matches. TRomano made one for you, and it's great.